# How to debug whats the issue in webview while loading website url in android

Tags: android, webview, web

My issue is in my android app i am loading my clients website in **android.webkit.Webview** component my all app is working fine there is not issue in my app, but in one section client wants to load single website page.

But i dont know as soon as i load website url using webview method

```
 mywebview.loadUrl(url);
```

My app is getting crash below is the log you can checkout:

```
03-09 16:26:59.927 25581-25581/com.niks.webviewapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(37)] "Typekit: the domain "autopearl.myshopify.com" isn't in the list of published domains for kit "jxm1pjf".", source: https://use.typekit.net/jxm1pjf.js (37)
03-09 16:27:00.468 25581-25581/com.niks.webviewapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'block-all-mixed-content'.
                                                              ", source: about:blank (0)
03-09 16:27:00.468 25581-25581/com.niks.webviewapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'upgrade-insecure-requests'.
                                                              ", source: about:blank (0)
03-09 16:27:00.470 25581-25581/com.niks.webviewapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'block-all-mixed-content'.
                                                              ", source: about:blank (0)
03-09 16:27:00.472 25581-25581/com.niks.webviewapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'upgrade-insecure-requests'.
                                                              ", source: about:blank (0)
03-09 16:27:00.620 25581-25581/com.niks.webviewapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(65)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null", source: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/javascripts/shopify_stats.js?v=6 (65)
03-09 16:27:00.921 25581-25581/com.niks.webviewapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'block-all-mixed-content'.
                                                              ", source: about:blank (0)
03-09 16:27:00.921 25581-25581/com.niks.webviewapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'upgrade-insecure-requests'.
                                                              ", source: about:blank (0)
03-09 16:27:02.654 25581-25581/com.niks.webviewapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(9)] "Facebook Pixel Warning: Multiple different pixels were detected on this page", source: https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js (9)
03-09 16:27:03.188 25581-25581/com.niks.webviewapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'block-all-mixed-content'.
                                                              ", source: about:blank (0)
03-09 16:27:03.188 25581-25581/com.niks.webviewapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'upgrade-insecure-requests'.
                                                              ", source: about:blank (0)
03-09 16:27:03.190 25581-25581/com.niks.webviewapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'block-all-mixed-content'.
                                                              ", source: about:blank (0)
03-09 16:27:03.190 25581-25581/com.niks.webviewapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'upgrade-insecure-requests'.
                                                              ", source: about:blank (0)
03-09 16:27:04.153 25581-25581/com.niks.webviewapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'block-all-mixed-content'.
                                                              ", source: about:blank (0)
03-09 16:27:04.153 25581-25581/com.niks.webviewapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'upgrade-insecure-requests'.
                                                              ", source: about:blank (0)
03-09 16:27:04.153 25581-25581/com.niks.webviewapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'block-all-mixed-content'.
                                                              ", source: about:blank (0)
```

You can try loading the website in android webview

Url : **https://autopearl.myshopify.com/account/login**
Note : I have tried loading this in chrome browser it is not getting crash.So please try loading in in android **android.webkit.Webview**

I want to tell exact problem in website due to which my app is crashing.
Please help?

Comment: refer https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content

Comment: @sasikumar I have gone through this link but how it is taking excessive memory i am not getting due to this warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable DomStorageEnabled AS True

Android

webview.settings.domStorageEnabled =true